# Updating a record in wp database

Tags: php, wordpress

Can somebody please help me here. I am trying to to an update to a WP database record using the following code. I am using the user ID of the current user to update the record but it doesn't want to update. Am I doing anything wrong?

```
If($_POST['Submit']) {


    $amount=$_POST['amount'];
    $period=$_POST['period'];
    //$current_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    $where = array('ID' => $current_user->ID);
    $subs = array('amount' => $amount, 'period' => $period);
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name  = $wpdb->prefix."wp_users";

    $wpdb->update($table_name, $subs, $where);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `$tablename` is incorrect. Instead, try:

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix."users";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked. I thought you add wp as that's how its named when you check it phpMyadmin

Comment: Cool - no problem :) Please upvote and accept my answer, and let me know if you have any more issues!

Answer (score 0):

First You need check the logs and try change table name:

```
If($_POST['Submit']) {


$amount=$_POST['amount'];
$period=$_POST['period'];
//$current_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

$where = array('ID' => $current_user->ID);
$subs = array('amount' => $amount, 'period' => $period);
global $wpdb;
$table_name  = $wpdb->prefix."users";

$wpdb->update($table_name, $subs, $where);
```